# Basic example from chaiscript.com throws an exception at runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio, chaiscript

I added the `include` directory of chaiscript to my Projects `Additional Dependencies` and compiled [this example](https://gist.github.com/lefticus/9190735#file-chaiscript_basic_example-cpp) successfully.
If I execute it though, it throws this exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x753D5B68 in CHAISCRIPT_TEST.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: chaiscript::exception::load_module_error at memory location 0x0103F0D8.
```

After further testing around chaiscript seems to complain about not finding the module `chaiscript_stdlib-5.8.0`
How do I fix that?

Comment: Could you please at least leave a comment why you downvote the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the [solution](http://chaiscript.com/examples.html#ChaiScript_Compiled_in_Stdlib_Example). The `std_lib` module has to be initialized the way the example shows.